# Library causes Build Errors in new Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to integrate [MetatoneOSC](https://github.com/cpmpercussion/MetatoneOSC) into a brand new Swift iOS project.

What I've done so far:

- Create new iOS Swift Project
- Drag folder full of .h and .m files into Xcode project
- Create a functioning bridging header (autocomplete now works for methods in the library) - `#import "MetatoneOSC/F53OSC.h"`
- Put the following code in `ViewController.swift`:

`let client = F53OSCClient.init()`

The build fails with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_F53OSCClient", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.F53OSCClient in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Each new class I use in my code creates a duplicate error, with a different class name after `$_F53OSC` in the error message.

I have tried setting up a new Objective-C project to make sure it's not a bridging error, and I get exactly the same error. Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally means you forgot to compile the relevant `.m` file. In you "Build Phases > Compile Sources" step for the target, make sure you've included all the relevant files. This doesn't always happen automatically if you just drag them into the project.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that adding them using the file picker instead of dragging them added everything to the Compile Sources